# How do I adjust subplots from a .fig file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, text, subplot, fig

I have a .fig file with 9 subplots, arranged 3 by 3. Now I want to add labels with I have written in plotlabels(i) to subplot i, on point (xcoordinates(i),0.01). I try this

```
plotlabels = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'];
xcoordinates = [30,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000];
fig = openfig('degreedistribution.fig');

for i = drange(1,9)
     subplot(3,3,i);
     text(xcoordinates(i),0.01,plotlabels(i),'FontWeight','bold'); hold on
end
```

The figure is returned with subplot 1, 4 and 7 (the left column) blanc. In the other subplots, the proper label is added in the right location. I have checked that the locations of the labels in subplot 1, 4 and 7 are compatible with the plots. So what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Its the axis, I assume.

as I don't have your figure, I tried without that line:

```
plotlabels = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'];
xcoordinates = [30,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000];
for i = drange(1,9)
   subplot(3,3,i);
   text(xcoordinates(i),0.01,plotlabels(i),'FontWeight','bold'); hold on; 
end
```

You can see that no labels are shown, however, all x axis are [0-1]. If I add the line `axis([0 2000 0 0.02])` after `text(...` then I can see all labels:

[image]

Comment: I have tried it, but the problem seems to be that the command 'subplot(3,3,i)' starts a new subplot in the case i=1,4,7, and overwrites my data. Even if I change the axis, the old plot is nowhere to be found..

Comment: @DM037 however, we can not reproduce any of that because you are not giving a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

A minimal working example would be helpful.

You can manually assign each text to its parent axis:

```
for i = 1:9
     t = text(xcoordinates(i),0.01,plotlabels(i),'FontWeight','bold'); 
     t.Parent = fig.Children(i);
end
```